# Creating Dataset with Python, scraping web

Tags: python, r, dataframe, web-scraping, rvest

I've looked on many posts, but haven't found a solution that quite does what I need.  First, I preface by saying I am new to Python (I'm using Python 2).

I am trying to gather data from a webpage (http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html).  Notice the nice html table.  I've been able to read this into a list without much issue.  However, also notice there are two columns with links.  I'd like to remove the first-link column (but I'm not sure how to do this since my data is in a list).

The second-link column is a bit more complicated.  I want to replace the title "Link" with "Last Statement".  Then , I want to visit each link provided, retrieve the last statement, and place it in the corresponding row of the original table I created a list for.

Finally, I want to print this list as a tab-delimited file that can be read into R as a data frame.

This is a lot for a noob to handle.  Please tell me if I'm approaching this problem correctly.  Below is the code I have thus far.  I'm missing a bit of what I want to do because I'm not sure how to start.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import html
import csv
import string
import sys

#obtain the main url with bigger data
main_url = "http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html"

#convert the html to BeautifulSoup
doc = requests.get(main_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc.text, 'lxml')

#find in html the table
tbl = soup.find("table", attrs = {"class":"os"})

#create labels for list rows by table headers
headings = [th.get_text() for th in tbl.find("tr").find_all("th")]

#convert the unicode to string
headers = []
for i in range(0,len(headings)-1):
    headers.append(str(headings[i]))

#access the remaining information
prisoners = []
for row in tbl.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    #attach the appropriate header to the appropriate corresponding data
    #also, converts unicode to string
    info = zip(headers, (str(td.get_text()) for td in row.find_all("td")))    
    #append each of the newly made rows
    prisoners.append(info)

#print each row of the list to a file for R
with open('output.txt', 'a') as output:
    for p in prisoners:
        output.write(str(p)+'\n')
output.close()
```

If you can help me figure out any of the three parts I'm struggling with, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

No need for UglyStew. R's concise, expressive scraping will work *just* fine.

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(pbapply)
library(dplyr)

URL <- "http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html"
pg <- read_html(URL)

nod <- html_nodes(pg, "table.os")[[1]]
tab <- html_table(nod)

last_urls <- html_attr(html_nodes(nod, xpath=".//tr/td[3]/a"), "href")
last_urls <- sprintf("http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/%s", last_urls)
last_st <- pbsapply(last_urls, function(x) {
  pg2 <- read_html(x)
  trimws(html_text(html_nodes(pg2, 
                              xpath=".//p[contains(., 'Last Statement')]/following-sibling::p")))
})

death_row <- mutate(tab[, -c(2:3)], last_statement=last_st)
death_row <- setNames(death_row, gsub("\\.", "_", tolower(make.names(colnames(death_row)))))
death_row <- mutate(death_row, date=as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y"))

glimpse(death_row)

## Observations: 537
## Variables: 9
## $ execution      (int) 537, 536, 535, 534, 533, 532, 531, 530, 529, 528, 527, 5...
## $ last_name      (chr) "Vasquez", "Ward", "Wesbrook", "Garcia", "Freeman", "Mas...
## $ first_name     (chr) "Pablo", "Adam", "Coy", "Gustavo", "James", "Richard", "...
## $ tdcj_number    (int) 999297, 999525, 999281, 999018, 999539, 999414, 999419, ...
## $ age            (int) 38, 33, 58, 43, 35, 43, 36, 33, 35, 27, 46, 67, 32, 34, ...
## $ date           (date) 2016-04-06, 2016-03-22, 2016-03-09, 2016-02-16, 2016-01...
## $ race           (chr) "Hispanic", "White", "White", "Hispanic", "White", "Whit...
## $ county         (chr) "Hidalgo", "Hunt", "Harris", "Collin", "Wharton", "Harri...
## $ last_statement (list) I just want to tell my family thank you, my mom and  da...
```

That took a minute or two to scrape and it's super-good of TX to have a site like that so [here a link to an R Data file of the resultant data frame](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpairgl4tkidius/tx_death_row.rda?dl=0) to avoid any more load on their servers.

Comment: THANK YOU.  I had tried R first because that's what I'm most familiar with, but I couldn't find decent documentation to help with the generalizations of patterns you have going on in xpath and sprintf.  So, my code ended where you have last_urls.  Do you have any suggestions for places I can look next time?

Comment: I learned XPath when I had much SGML to process back in the day. XML/XPath are things that drive people to drink, so I wouldn't recommend delving too deep unless you really have to.  I'm pretty sure I could have made a CSS selector for said XPath but I think in XPath (unfortunately). Best way to get good is to practice. I haven't seen a comprehensive "cookbook"-like reference but I'll drop a note back here if I find one.